# How can I set selected option selected in vue.js 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My component vue is like this :

```
<template>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" :required @change="changeLocation">
        <option :selected>Choose Province</option>
        <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id" >{{ option.name }}</option>
    </select>
</template>
```

I use this : `<option :selected>Choose Province</option>` to selected

But whene executed, on the gulp watch exist error

The error like this :

> ERROR in
>   ./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler.js?id=data-v-53777228!./~/vue-load
>   er/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/bootst
>   rap/LocationBsSelect.vue Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   token (28:4)

Seems my step is wrong

How can I solve it?

Comment: You mention there is an error. You should include it in the question.

Comment: @nicooga, I had update my question

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/308 -https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/308#issuecomment-314248619 - this fixed my issue

Answer (score 81):

## Handling the errors

You are binding properties to nothing. `:required` in

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="selected" :required @change="changeLocation">
```

and `:selected` in

```
<option :selected>Choose Province</option>
```

If you set the code like so, your errors should be gone:

```
<template>
  <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" :required @change="changeLocation">
    <option>Choose Province</option>
    <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id" >{{ option.name }}</option>
 </select>
</template>
```

## Getting the select tags to have a default value

1. you would now need to have a `data` property called `selected` so that v-model works. So,

   ```
   {
     data () {
       return {
         selected: "Choose Province"
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. If that seems like too much work, you can also do it like:

   ```
   <template>
     <select class="form-control" :required="true" @change="changeLocation">
      <option :selected="true">Choose Province</option>
      <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id" >{{ option.name }}</option>
     </select>
   </template>
   ```

---

## When to use which method?

1. You can use the `v-model` approach if your default value depends on some data property.
2. You can go for the second method if your default selected value happens to be the first `option`.
3. You can also handle it programmatically by doing so:

   ```
   <select class="form-control" :required="true">
     <option 
      v-for="option in options" 
      v-bind:value="option.id"
      :selected="option == '<the default value you want>'"
     >{{ option }}</option>
   </select>
   ```

Comment: This `:selected="option == '<the default value you want>'"` helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: @Amesh Venugopal, I tried this `<option v-for="recipe in recipes" :selected="option == 'Sugar Cookies (Default)'">{{ recipe }}</option>` but the first option is still blank in the select list.  Would you post fiddle showing how this works?

Comment: :selected="option == '<the default value you want>'" help me to

Answer (score 58):

The simplest answer is to set the selected option to `true` or `false`.

```
<option :selected="selectedDay === 1" value="1">1</option>
```

Where the data object is:

```
data() {
    return {
        selectedDay: '1',
        // [1, 2, 3, ..., 31]
        days: Array.from({ length: 31 }, (v, i) => i).slice(1)
    }
}
```

This is an example to set the selected month day:

```
<select v-model="selectedDay" style="width:10%;">
    <option v-for="day in days" :selected="selectedDay === day">{{ day }}</option>
</select>
```

On your data set:

```
{
    data() {
        selectedDay: 1,
        // [1, 2, 3, ..., 31]
        days: Array.from({ length: 31 }, (v, i) => i).slice(1)
    },
    mounted () {
        let selectedDay = new Date();
        this.selectedDay = selectedDay.getDate(); // Sets selectedDay to the today's number of the month
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but not because of the `:selected` bindings. Using `v-model` means that any `checked`, `value`, and `selected` attributes are ignored. Please see basic usage here, where this ignoring of specific attributes is described - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: You can also use the short version: `:selected="selectedDay === 1"`

Comment: @LucasMorgan, when using a component whose list of options is dynamically obtained on mount, the `v-model` does not seem to work. This solution is the only one that I have found so far working in that scenary.

Comment: A person could also shorten that by some logic similar to this: `this.days = [...Array(31)];` and then `<option v-for="(_, day) in days" :selected="selectedDay === day">{{ day }}</option>`. Good luck out there.

Comment: With that said, I think a person should also probably use a library for date picking because the person will enter into a world of pain if they try to start accounting for days in the month and leap years. It's a well-characterized problem possibly better left to a library that already has unit tests and a nice API.

Answer (score 13):

```
<select v-model="challan.warehouse_id">
<option value="">Select Warehouse</option>
<option v-for="warehouse in warehouses" v-bind:value="warehouse.id"  >
   {{ warehouse.name }}
</option>
```

Here "challan.warehouse_id" come from "challan" object you get from:

```
editChallan: function() {
    let that = this;
    axios.post('/api/challan_list/get_challan_data', {
    challan_id: that.challan_id
 })
 .then(function (response) {
    that.challan = response.data;
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
    that.errors = error;
  }); 
 }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 11):

You simply need to remove v-bind (:) from selected and required attributes.
Like this :-

```html
<template>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" required @change="changeLocation">
        <option selected>Choose Province</option>
        <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id" >{{ option.name }}</option>
    </select>
</template>
```

You are not binding anything to the vue instance through these attributes thats why it is giving error.

Comment: Using your example gives an attribute called "selected" with the value selected...

selected= "selected"

Answer (score 2):

My code for reactive multiselect

```
data() {
    return {
        article: {title: 'aaaaa', 'categoriesIds': [1,3], ...},
        selectCategories: {1: 'xxx', 2: 'www', 3: 'yyy', 4: 'zzz'},
    }
},
```

template

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="content">Categories</label>
     <select name="categories" 
         v-model="article.categoriesIds" 
         id="categories" 
         multiple 
         class="form-control col-md-5" 
         size="6">
         <option v-for="(category, key) in selectCategories" 
             :key="key" 
             v-bind:value="key">{{category}}</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Selected items are binded to the **article.categoriesIds** array.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, which I often find more reliable, is you could add a directive to your `app.js` or wherever you are initiating your VueJS, eg:

```
Vue.directive('attr', (el, binding) => {
  if (binding.value === true) binding.value = ''
  if (binding.value === '' || binding.value) {
    el.setAttribute(binding.arg, binding.value)
  }
})
```

You can then utilise `v-attr` to set an attribute, eg:

```
<option value="Western Australia" v-attr:selected="form.state == 'Western Australia'">Western Australia</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand the main goal is to set "Choose Province" as the default. I tried other options but the simple one worked for me the best:

```
<template>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" :required @change="changeLocation">
        <option>Choose Province</option> # just an option with no selected or assigned v-model
        <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id" >{{ option.name }}</option>
    </select>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make as follow using v-model in the select tag
and using library useForm from vue and make the default value of form.category = choose or any default value you want.

```
<script setup>
import { Head, Link, useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
const form = useForm({
    category: 'choose',
    file: null,
});
</script>

<template>

                    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-5">
                        <label for="category" class="font-black">Choose A Category</label>
                        <select id="category" v-model="form.category" required >
                            <option value="choose" disabled>choose</option>
                            <option value="Other">other</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="bg-red-200 rounded-lg p-2" v-if="form.errors.category">
                            {{ form.errors.category }}
                        </div>
                    </div>


</template>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.