# How to implement options using "v-for" with vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I store the selected option? I am using Vue.js.
I have an array of country objects stored in `destinations`. Each country in this array should be listed as an option. The selected country should be stored in `destination`. I don't know why but it seems that nothing is stored in `destination` because if I try to access it I just get `NaN`.

```
<fieldset>
    <label for="country">Country</label>
       <select name="country" id="country" v-model="destination">
         <option v-for="dest in destinations" :value="dest" :key="dest">dest.displayName</option>

       </select>
<\fieldset>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you show us what data is inside destinations? Is destination declared in your data() ?

Comment: yes, "destinations" and "destination" is declared in data().                               An object stored in "destinations" looks like this: {isoCode: 'SY',
                                      displayName: 'Syria',}

Comment: have you checked this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43839066/how-can-i-set-selected-option-selected-in-vue-js-2

Comment: replace dest.displayName with {{dest.displayName}}

Comment: Thanks, I think that answers my question.